# gradle build file for datavec example in deeplearning4j

Tags: java, gradle, machine-learning, deep-learning

trying to run some of the datavec exanples. i have the datavec example code in my project source directory.

```
my gradle build file is:

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    mainClassName="Main"
    dependencies {
        //compile 'org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-spark:0.4-rc3.9'
        compile 'org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-spark_2.11:0.9.1_spark_1'
        compile 'org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:0.9.1'
        compile 'org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:0.9.1'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

edit: fixed bad spark version.

the main program is:

```
import org.deeplearning4j.api.storage.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Persistable p=null;
    }
}
```

which builds and runs without any of the example code in the project, so the core jar(s) are there.

gradle gets a:

```
 error: error reading C:\Users\ray\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.
    spark\spark-core_2.11\1.4.0\9c171726a4c87f7ccce877061ad0113e222d6021\spark-core_
    2.11-1.4.0.jar; error in opening zip file
```

does anyone have a build file for dl4j that will let one build and run some of the examples?

thanks

edit2: using the correct version and deleting the gradle caches make it work.

```
D:\ray\dev\ml\trygradleanddl4j>gradlew clean run
:clean
:compileJava
error: error reading C:\Users\ray\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-  
...                                             
13 errors
:compileJava FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

using the correct version and deleting the gradle caches make it work.